# How do I assign a <a href to a image without it ruining flexbox?

Tags: flexbox

I'm trying to move a picture, and I have it assigned as a href so that once you click on it you get to a new section.

But when I have the a-href I can't move the image. It's kinda stuck with the parent of the container, but I want to move it on my own.. only way to do that is removing the <a href..

```
 <a href="#section2">
      <img class="contact-icon" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/16219839/mail.png" width="32x32" alt="contact"></a>
```

I have tried doing this:

```
      <img class="contact-icon" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/16219839/mail.png" width="32x32" alt="contact"></a>
```

So I removed the A href section, but I I don't want that, I want to have it so the image is clickable.